# Sql Query, how can I make 23,4585688 as a round value like 23,000000

Tags: mysql, sql

If there is a value resulting like 23,948948....then how can I make this as a round value like 23,000000

```
select ROUND(gdp/population, 0) from world where GDP >= 1000000000000
```

This is the output, I am getting...

```
ROUND(gdp/pop..
66442
11115
44739
6122
39620
```

Where as the actual result is,

```
ROUND(gdp/pop..
Australia   66000
Brazil  11000
Canada  45000
China   6000
France  40000
```

Comment: Does MySQL support floor() function?

Answer (score 0):

```
select ROUND(gdp/(population*1000), 0)*1000 from world where GDP >= 1000000000000
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select ROUND(gdp/population, -3) from world where GDP >= 1000000000000
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use query somewhat as follows:

```
 select country_name, round(gdp/pop) from  WORLD where GDP >= 1000000000000;
```